# exiting from complete application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i can close/exit button on my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260409/how-i-can-close-exit-button-on-my-app)

Hi,sir 
I need code to exit from the android application directly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i can close/exit button on my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260409/how-i-can-close-exit-button-on-my-app) (and about a bajillion other questions here).

Answer (score 0):

To exit an activity call

```
finish();
```

Comment: i need to come from total application not from an activity

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question: [How to finish series of open sub-activities from one activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600969/how-to-finish-series-of-open-sub-activities-from-one-activity)

Either of the methods listed there should work:

> Generally one doesn't need to quit applicatios in Android. There's a long answer from CommonsWare here explaining why. However, there are a few ways it can be done. One such way is the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP which brings the targeted activity to the top of the stack and closes anything else that may have been open since. You'd use this if you had a button that brought the user back from wherever they were to the 'main menu' activity. That button would send an intent to start the 'main menu' with the CLEAR_TOP flag. The 'main menu' could then close with a simple finish(), and you'd know that none of the other activities were still open.
>
> Another way is that if you started the other activities with startActivityForResult, you can use finishActivity(requestCode) to close all activities that were started with that request code.
>
> However, as I wrote above, generally you shouldn't need to do this.
>
> ANSWERED BY Steve H https://stackoverflow.com/users/235654/steve-h